# Rewrite Rule in Apache/htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

1. I'm trying to redirect user request to my domain in .htaccess file.
2. My requirement is for example if user request for example.co/abc it should redirect to www.example.co/abc.
3. Below is my rewrite rule.

---

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co/Abc [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/Abc)$ https://www.example.co/$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

1. After adding the above two lines in my .htaccess file it is redirecting from example.co to www.example.co
2. I tried in different ways still not getting where i'm doing mistake.
3. Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{www.example.co} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(/*)$ https://www.example.co/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?(Abc)/?$ https://www.example.co/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Make leading slash optional by using `RewriteRule ^/?(Abc)/?$ https://www.example.co/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}` can not contain `/Abc`

Comment: Thanks for your replies tried with @anubhava suggestion still not working

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question ?

Comment: yes added @anubhava

Comment: i'm trying to redirect "example.co/Abc" to "www.example.co/Abc"

Comment: yes my first rule will redirect non-www to www but in my case if I request "example.co/blog" it should go to "www.example.co/blog" but it is resulting "www.example.co"

Comment: So in both cases you are adding `www` right?

Comment: yes exactly @anubhava

Comment: That is my point. If generic rule is already adding `www` then you won't need to have a separate rule for `/abc`